# Gridview Bulk Update

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, web-controls, gridviewrow

From this link:

[asp.net grid view bulk updating all cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8491026/1270384)

I did the following:

```
 protected void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)

       // {

        int RowIndex = 0;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[RowIndex];

            Int32 intresortID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["TypeID"]);
            Label dtm = row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
            Label strRoomType = row.FindControl("strRoomTypeLabel") as Label;
            Label strDescription = row.FindControl("Label3") as Label;
            TextBox Qty = row.FindControl("intQtyTextBox") as TextBox;
            TextBox Price = row.FindControl("curPriceTextBox") as TextBox;
            Label intWSCode = row.FindControl("intWSCodeLabel") as Label;

            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["bedbankstandssConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update tblAvailable set intqty=@intQty, curprice=@curprice where intresortid=@intresortid and dtm=@dtm and strroomtype=@strroomtype",Con);


            //SqlParameter ddtm= new SqlParameter("@dtm",dtm) ;
            //SqlParameter sstrRoomType = new SqlParameter("@strroomtype", strRoomType);
            //SqlParameter qQty = new SqlParameter("@intQty", Qty);
            //SqlParameter pPrice =new SqlParameter("@curPrice",Price);
            //SqlParameter resortID = new SqlParameter("@intResortID", intresortID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtm",dtm.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strroomtype",strRoomType.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intQty", Qty.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@curPrice",Price.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intResortID",intresortID);
            Con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            DataBind();





       // }
    }
```

But only one row gets updated, the first one.

Would somebody be able to tell me where I went wrong please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have commented out the loop, so why are you wondering that only one row is updated?

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    // ...
}
```

Apart from that, use the [`using-statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) for your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to ensure that is gets disposed/closed.

```
using(SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update tblAvailable set intqty=@intQty, curprice=@curprice where intresortid=@intresortid and dtm=@dtm and strroomtype=@strroomtype",Con))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```